# Factorize columns in two different DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames and in each of them I have a categorical column `col`. I want to replace all the categories with numbers, so I decided to do it this fashion:

`df1['col'] = pd.factorize(df1['col'])[0]`

Now the question is how can I code `df2[col]` in the same way? And how can I also code categories that are present in`df2[col]` but not in `df1[col]`?

Comment: Thanks @yatu. I've made an edit, could you please take a look at the last question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

enc = LabelEncoder()
df1['col'] = enc.fit_transform(df1['col'])
df2['col'] = enc.transform(df2['col'])
```

---

for unseen label, this may be a solution:

```
enc = LabelEncoder()
enc.fit(df1['col'])
diz_map = dict(zip(enc.classes_, enc.transform(enc.classes_)+1))

for i in set(df2['col']).difference(df1['col']):
    diz_map[i] = 0

df1['col'] = [diz_map[i] for i in df1['col'].values]
df2['col'] = [diz_map[i] for i in df2['col'].values]
```

you map as 0 all the unseen values in df2['col']

Comment: You might want to add some explanations along with the code to make it a little clearer for op

Comment: @Marco Thanks a lot! One more thing, what if df2 has also some new labels, not preset in df1? How can I overcome that?

Comment: This won't work, why 0? 0 is most an unseen value by the encoder. And if it is not, it is wrongly mapped

Comment: I tried to concat values from df1 and df2 and apply it to df1 and df2 separately but then sizes are different

Comment: @yatu the solution works.... as 0 for convenience. The first class encoded in LabelEncoder is always 0 so we are sure it exists, at the same time we operate a translation of 1 in other numerical class enc.transform(enc.classes_)+1 so no mistake